# VS 2022 cannot find vcpkg toolchain

Tags: c++, cmake, vcpkg

I am trying to integrate vcpkg into an existing CMake Project using Visual Studio 2022. I have tried to follow online resources on the installation and setup process. Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/cmake-presets-vs?view=msvc-170#enable-vcpkg-integration) Microsoft document on CMake projects, I added the CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE variable to cacheVariables in my CMakePresets.json. They recommend using the VCPKG_ROOT environment variable to reach the vcpkg.cmake file, as in `$env{VCPKG_ROOT}/scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`. However, when I try to generate the CMake cache, Cmake throws an error stating `Could not find toolchain file: /scripts/buildsystems/vcpkg.cmake`. This leads me to believe that the environment variable is not being set somehow. I have ran the bootstrap batch file and the command `vckpg integrate install` so I am at a loss for what is causing the problem.

Comment: The document says environment variable for VCPKG_ROOT must be set. It seems you missed setting env. variable. Don't forget that you should restart VS2022 after setting it.